# Open a cash drawer using a RJ11 DIO 12/24V port in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I recently bought a [Shuttle All-In-One X50V4](http://www.shuttle.eu/products/all-in-one/x50v4/), together with its extension card [POS01](http://www.shuttle.eu/products/xpc-accessories/pos01/) (it was a bundle were the card was already mounted).

I also bought a [Metapace K-1](http://www.metapace.com/K-1.html) cash drawer.

I know that most of the time, the cash drawer is connected to the printer, which is itself connected to the computer, and sending a specific sequence of characters to the printer triggers the openning of the cash drawer.

In my case, I would like to be able to open the cash drawer without any printer. This should be possible according to what the POS01 doc says (RJ11 DIO 12/24V port for cash drawer).

I have read somewhere that I simply need to send a pulse to the cash drawer, but I have no idea how to do that... I have read through everything I could find from the two manufacturers, nothing came up. The 4 COM ports of the POS01 board are detected on Windows (at least they are in the list of devices), as is the LPT port, but I don't know how to check for the RJ11 DIO port.

My final goal is to be able to open the cash drawer from a C# application (WPF), but right now I would like to do some testing using either the DOS command line, powershell or python.

Hope someone can help, and please forgive me if this is not the right place to ask!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/360123/can-i-directly-open-an-mmf-cash-drawer-through-rj-11-port is worth a read. I suppose its on topic, and it isn't *quite* off topic other than the programming part. I'd be inclined to leave it as is, and note the other question isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Shuttle support and they send me a small `CashDrawer.exe` software tool. The tool is not publicly available, so anyone facing the same issue should directly contact Shuttle support using [this form](http://www.shuttle.eu/fr/support/service-apres-vente/support-form/).

Some additional information that may be useful to anyone wanting to use that platform as a POS:

1. The executable only work if you run it as administrator.
2. There is no information about the output voltage (12V or 24V)... It works with my Metapace K-1, that is all I know.
3. The executable was shipped with a `WinIO32.dll`, thus I assumed it is using low level I/O, but since I only have the executable I cannot really create my own code (I will have to call their executable from my own application).

Comment: Presumably, you can capture all com port traffic and isolate the sequence of commands

Comment: @Yorik It is not a COM port or my problem would not exist, it is a raw I/O port.

Comment: I think they are still com ports or com-based printers. ( see also: http://superuser.com/questions/360123/can-i-directly-open-an-mmf-cash-drawer-through-rj-11-port )

Comment: @Yorik I don't see them in the available COM or LPT ports, and trying to open any port others than the one listed in the device manager fails, so I doubt they are. I have already tried all the "stuff" I have found here and on google, nothing worked (would not have posted this question if I had found something working). Moreover, as mentioned in my answer, the tool is shipped with the `WinIO32.dll`, which deals with raw I/O port, so I think these are definitively raw I/O port (I will try to see what's in the tool if I can to confirm).

Comment: Useful? http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=394289&av=571979 (winio32 looks like a 3rd party library?)

Comment: @Yorik I have already read that, unfortunately I did not manage to retrieve the port address, so I was not able to do anything with it... Basically, it is a pretty expensive equipment (for me), and the port I want to use can output a 24V pulse so I don't want to try which could basically broke it...

Comment: If they use [this WinIO library](http://www.internals.com/) you can make it work without admin account and also find out how to use it in your own software! To let it work as non-admin, you have to load the driver. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=394289&av=571979#WinIO%20library).
To see what exactly they are calling in the dll, use [ApiMonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). You can then do the same in your own software or post the commands here ;) (this always works, but if it is another WinIO32.dll with unclear license you can't use it)

Comment: @Josef I have checked the content of both `.dll` using [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) and they seem to have the same content (even if they do not have the same size... ). I cannot test your "solution" right now, but I will definitively give it a try as soon as I can, thanks!

Comment: @Holt nice. So it is probably just a older version of the library. Since the full source to the dll is available, you could also just change it to dump out the important parameters if you don't like ApiMonitor. The important thing is probably just one (ore a few) call to `SetPortVal` and/or `SetPhysLong`

Comment: The voltage is set using two jumpers, according to the manual.